# Wordpress Page doesn't load the template selected

Tags: pages, page-template, template-hierarchy

I've created a new page called `Work` and I've added it on the navigation bar; after that I've created a file called `work.php` in which I want to style the page mentioned above.

The problem is that the page doesn't show the new template created in `work.php` even if I selected it on the Wordpress graphic interface, but instead it shows the template of `index.php`. Does anyone know where the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: That isn't how custom page templates or post specific templates work, have you looked at the template hierarchy diagram?

Comment: the template name should be page-work.php

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the template hierarchy diagram and I have followed those instructions. I've tried to use page-work.php but the results are the same. It is weird that it doesn't work because I've also used this process for the other pages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this question is 3 years old, but I just solved what sounds like a similar situation.

- I have a page with a slug **join**
- I created **page-join.php** and my issue was that it wasn't being referenced
- I resolved the issue by changing the Join page's **Page Attributes > Template** from what was selected to **Default Template**

[image]